# How exactly do Copper salts help in Sandmeyer Reaction (Halogenation)?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I have searched a quite few sources on mechanism for Sandmeyer's reaction, but couldn't find (and understand) how CuCl for example helps in replacement of N2 from Benzene diazonium chloride and gives Chlorobenzene? In Solomon-Fryhle-Snyder's regarding the mechanism its been given that "*the mechanisms of these replacement reactions are not full undertstood*", is this true and the reason most sources don't have mechanisms for Sandmeyers Halogenation reaction?

Comment: See: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/34948/why-use-potassium-iodide-instead-of-copper-iodide-in-sandmeyer-reaction